# How to register client app in gcm?

Tags: android, json, google-cloud-messaging

I have gone through gcm client setup and registration codes in gcm documentation. But i have few more doubts

1. when we run gcm quick start we use a json configuration file which contains all details of sender id and project and so on.

2.But when we create a customized client app.Do we need a json file?or How my client app recognize sender id/project id to get registered with sever app.

Comment: You should try to find a solution to your problem before asking here.

Comment: I just want to know the importance of json configuration file.Is it necessary when we write client side code.

Answer (score 1):

Check this official documentation [link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client).

Update after comment

[Here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) you will find the documentation about the Push Message structure. Although this is from the Server-side point of view.